# How to get the literal value of a variable's variable?

Tags: bash, variables

Here's what I'm asking:

```
a="achoo"
b="bah"
c="clap"
d="dong"
e="eew"

vowels="$a $e"
consonants="$b $c $d"
```

- `echo $vowels` outputs `achoo eew`, but sometimes I want `$a $e`
- `echo $consonants` outputs `bah clap dong`, but sometimes I want `$b $c $d`

Of course, I could just use `head` or `sed` to parse from the script itself, but I won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to avoid variable expansion when setting `vowels` and `consonants`:

```
vowels='$a $e'
consonants='$b $c $d'
```

You're out of luck otherwise; the expansion happened at the time of assignment, so `vowels` and `consonants` no longer have any references to `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, or `$e` anymore after they're assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the script itself. There is no literal value of `vowels` other than `achoo eew`. The string has been interpolated at the moment you assigned it and it's the only value that exists after that line.

If this is your source, you can use indirection via eval and modify the pattern:

```
> a=123
> b='$a'
> echo $b
$a
> eval 'echo $b'
$a
> eval "echo $b"
123
```

But that will cause you a lot of problems in case there are any additional quotes in `$b`

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, around them:

```
vowels='$a $e'
consonants='$b $c $d'
```